# What type are these two sentences with imperative clauses

Tags: syntax, compound-complex

Quotes are from *The Old Man and the Sea* by Ernest Hemingway

> 1. Remember, no matter how little you want to, that you must eat him
>    in the morning.
> 2. Remember, he said to himself.

I thought the second one would be complex sentence as it is similar pattern to direct speech ("Remember," he said. - that would be complex, right?) but not sure anymore as it feels like imperative clause Remember can stand on its own.

Similarly at first I thought that the first sentence is complex-compound but if the Remember is independent clause it can't be. How is it, then?

Comment: What is the source of these two quotes, please.  You can [edit] your question to add the source

Comment: Sorry, didn't think of that. The source is The Old Man and the Sea by Ernest Hemingway.